# Google Play Game Services - Spurious conflicts?

Tags: ios, google-play-games, cloud-storage

We're adding Cloud Storage (AppState) support to one of our iOS games but there's a strange behavior in our app I don't quite understand:

1. The app starts and signs in the user.
2. Some data is successfully saved to the cloud (say, into the key 0).
3. The app is restarted and again it signs in the user.
4. At this point, it doesn't matter if I load or save, I always get a conflict the first time I access the cloud storage after a restart.

Does this make sense? Is the iOS library supposed to always return a conflict after restarting the app? I would have guessed that the app kept the version string of the last data after a restart so it wouldn't result normally into a conflict.

Is there a way to debug what's the iOS library doing? I was thinking I could sniff the network traffic but it's not possible because everything goes through https.

**UPDATE (Dec/03/13):**
I managed to setup an HTTP proxy to inspect the API calls being done behind the scenes by the iOS library, I can confirm that even though the save operation (aka update) in the 4th step is working (i.e. the correct currentStateVersion is used and the HTTP response doesn't show any conflicts), the library still calls the conflictHandler of the updateForKey method.

Comment: I'm setting up a HTTP proxy to inspect the network traffic and see exactly what's the library doing (basically to determine what version strings is using with every request) hopefully this will help me understand better the problem

Comment: It's funny that the Android version of the API provides the version string to the conflict callback but not in iOS :( I could use it to check if it's an actual conflict.

Comment: Hmm... I think you may be on to something. This might actually be a legit bug in the iOS library. Let me follow up with you on the bug database.

Comment: Here's a [link](https://code.google.com/p/play-games-platform/issues/detail?id=55&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Platform%20Summary%20Stars) to the bug report @Todd.